# NodeJS, MongoDB - Adding sequential ID and promise problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm coming from MS SQL so to make things easier in my mind, I'm trying to create the equivalent of a sequential primary key. Using some online articles and API references I've constructed the following:

```
  function getNextSequence(name) {
    var ret = db.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: name },
      { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
      {returnNewDocument: true}
    )

    return ret.seq;
  }

  console.log(getNextSequence("sms_id"))

  db.collection('SMS').insertOne({
      "_id":getNextSequence("sms_id"),
      record
    }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to insert record', err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2));
  });
```

The problem is the getNextSequence() function is continuing before the findOneAndUpdate() method inside of it finishes. After some debugging, I've determined that it is a promise that is pending, so I tried making the following changes:

```
  function getNextSequence(name) {
    var ret = db.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: name },
      { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
      {returnNewDocument: true}
    ).then(() => {
      return ret.seq
    });
  }
```

But it still continues on. How can I get it to wait for the promise to finish?

Answer (score 2):

You want to construct a sequence of async executions, which is simple with Promises by returning them throughout your code:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
  return db.collection('counters').findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: name },
    { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
    {returnNewDocument: true}
  ).then(ret => ret.seq);
}
```

And then using the function:

```
getNextSequence('sms_id').then((seq) => {
  return db.collection('SMS').insertOne({
    "_id": seq,
    record
  });
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2));
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Unable to insert record', err);
});
```

Note that the error passed to the `.catch` callback can either be from `getNextSequence` **or** the `insertOne` method call on the `SMS` collection.

If you return another promise from within the callback of a Promise's `.then`-call, the next `.then`-call will wait for that promise to fulfill. See the below snippet for an example:

```js
function waitAndLog (msg, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(msg)
      resolve()
    }, ms)
  })
}

waitAndLog("there", 1000).then(() => {
  return waitAndLog("is", 1000)
}).then(() => {
  return waitAndLog("no", 1000)
}).then(() => {
  return waitAndLog("spoon", 1000)
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Sequence complete")
})
```